# Status push notifications via webhooks on sandbox

Tags: uber-api

I am able to post trip requests, get estimates and ask for trip statuses, both in sandbox and live.

However, I am starting implementing status push notifications via webhooks and have hit a problem: I don't receive the notification (on sandbox). I have tried a couple of different URLs and servers to no avail. When pushing the notification ourselves from postman it works.

Do status push notifications via webhooks work on sandbox? If not, is there a way to test them?

Comment: care to share any code?  see [ask]

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Webhooks documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/webhooks#section-reference) you should receive notifications every time you [update the status of a ride request](https://developer.uber.com/docs/sandbox#section-request)  in sandbox mode.

> Sandbox
>
> When making Requests in the sandbox environment, we will also emit
>   webhook events for simulated trips. **The requests.status_changed event
>   will be emitted every time the status of a simulated Request changes.**
>
> The requests.receipt_ready event will be emitted once a Request’s
>   status changes to completed.

Is you Webhook URL **HTTPS** enabled?

If this doesn't work you should consult the support team by visiting https://help.uber.com or by emailing support@uber.com.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an easier way to debug, try setting up [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)
and then change the webhook URL in your developer dashboard to the link you get from Ngrok. That should allow you to debug the Webhooks issue on your local machine and verify that there is nothing wrong with your deployment setup (lack of HTTPS could definitely be the culprit as Mnemonic Flow said)